# Carga de archivos en Laravel, ya en hosting

Tags: laravel, servidor, hosting, upload, storage

Estoy con un problema en mi aplicación. Armé un sistema donde el cliente debe cargar unos productos con su respectiva imagen.
Pero al subir el proyecto al hosting no encuentro la falla del por qué no carga la imagen.
Debo aclarar que la carpeta de laravel la tengo fuera del public_html, y no estoy usando el dominio principal, sino que uso un dominio extra alojado en el servidor, por eso en el config del path van a ver que no apunta al public_html.

Acá el código:

**Controlador**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request -> validate(['name' => 'required']);
        $request -> validate(['description' => 'required']);
        $request -> validate(['price' => 'required']);

        $newProduct = new App\Product;

        $newProduct -> name = $request -> name;
        $newProduct -> description = $request -> description;
        $newProduct -> price = $request -> price;

        if ( $request -> hasFile('photo') ) {
            $file = $request -> file("photo");
            $fileUpload = Storage::disk('public') -> put('img/products', $file);
            $newProduct -> photo = $fileUpload;
        }

        $newProduct -> save();

        return back() -> with('status', 'Los datos fueron guardados.');
    }
```

**filesystem**

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            //'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

y acá tengo registrado el path

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public',function(){
            return'/home1/cliente/dominio.com/carta';
        });
    }
```

Alguna sugerencia de cuál es el problema?

Comment: Cuál sería el problema? Estás pudiendo guardar en el disco las imágenes que subes, pero no puedes recuperarlas?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no se guardan las imágenes

Comment: Te lanza algún error? En la tabla que corresponde a Product de la base de datos guarda algo en la columna photo?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No, y revisé el log y tampoco aparece ningún error...si guarda el nombre de la imagen en la DB

Comment: Sólo el nombre o todo el path? O sea, algo así `C5HBeK06bbf5BQtGVUonHJykPIFMYWduuzbvPwsb.jpeg` o algo así `img/products/C5HBeK06bbf5BQtGVUonHJykPIFMYWduuzbvPwsb.jpeg`?

Comment: todo el path guarda en la DB

Comment: Podrías hacer un dd de public_path() y mostrarnos el resultado? `dd( public_path() );`. Puede ser en el controlador mismo o en una vista. O sie es un dato sensible, no lo publiques, pero te va a servir para ubicar el path completo que laravel toma como el directorio público. También puede servir ver si puedes obtener los archivos en ese directorio con `dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->files('img/products'));`

Comment: Acá está el resultado del primer dd 
"/home1/cliente/dominio.com/carta"

y este es el 2do
array:3 [▼ 0 => "img/products/A1TcDBGpWHpZFqI0BCks2RgomFh6KZg5aVidhRqK.jpeg" 1 => "img/products/cmEHoBELP96WK0yN0jiS9c7lLSsRMLNn967hEPRd.jpeg" 2 => "img/products/lJYiaWqvkA7NIreRpWk6V1XZXDE3XxnzcOlye14u.jpeg" ]

Comment: Lo que te muestra en el 2do parecen ser los archivos que subiste, entonces, sí los estaría guardando en el disco

Comment: Claro, pero esos archivos en realidad son los q subí cuando lo tenía en local, pero ahora en online no los sube

Comment: Finalmente pude resolverlo. Por alguna razón q desconozco me estaba creando una carpeta dentro de la carpeta de Laravel donde estaba guardando los archivos. Así que lo que hice fue colocar directamente como string el root del disco public y ahora lo guarda donde corresponde.